# How to set the filename when uploading in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I am using the following code to upload a file and save it on the disk. The filename is like:

> BodyPart4353453453

E.g. When I upload a file called alfa.txt it will be saved as BodyPart24245343.

How can I set the filename each time?

```
var uploadFolder = "/Content/Images/" + listingId;
var provider = GetMultipartProvider(uploadFolder);
var result = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
```

Comment: Explain what you mean by *'set the filename each time'*. What's the intended behavior and what do you have now?

Comment: @OndrejTucny E.g. When I upload a file called alfa.txt it will be saved as BodyPart24245343.

Comment: And the problem is…? You are describing AS IS state. What's your TO BE state? Your question is unclear.

Comment: Well any name would do; Lets say the original filename

Answer (score 1):

Try somthing like this.

```
// change file name with its extension
    var fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + 
        System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);

    var uploadUrl = Server.MapPath("~/uploads");

    file.SaveAs(Path.Combine(uploadUrl, fileName));
```